# Only show scrollbar when page scrolls in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html page of different kinds of images in a `<div>` with following CSS property:

```
.images_container {
   position: relative;
   height: calc(100% - 200px);
   padding-top: 20px;
   overflow: auto;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Currently page scrollbar is showing but I want to show the scrollbar only when user scrolls the page. Is this possible in CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: You can only control overflow with CSS. Scrollbar visibility is an OS-level setting.

Comment: @Sheikh James  can you please try height: calc(100vh - 200px);

Answer (score 12):

If you hook up on the elements `scroll` event, you could do something like this, where you set the `inner` to `width: 100%` and a `padding-right: 20px`. (the padding right value need to be bigger than the scrollbar is wide)

That will push the scrollbar out of view, and on scroll you remove the padding, init a timer which will reset the padding if one stop scrolling

```js
(function(timer) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('.inner');
    el.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    (function(el){
      el.style.padding = '0';
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.paddingRight = '20px';      
      }, 100);    
    })(el);
    })
  })
})();
```

```css
.outer {
  height: 180px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some
    content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some
    content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Updated, toggling a class, using [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), instead of an inline style, which might be a more recommended way.

```js
(function(timer) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('.inner');
    el.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    (function(el){
      el.classList.add('scroll');
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        el.classList.remove('scroll');
      }, 100);    
    })(el);
    })
  })
})();
```

```css
.outer {
  height: 180px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.inner.scroll {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some
    content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some
    content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br> Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks exactly like my answer.

Comment: @Troyer Yes it does, though as you extended the linked answer in yours, I did the same, but also made a good explanation and a fully working code with also hides the scrollbar when one stop scrolling...so in another way, very different...and I will upvote yours as it is a good start

Answer (score 3):

Extending this question: [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll/16671476#16671476).

You can use this trick like this:

```js
document.getElementById("child").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("child").style.paddingRight = '0px';
}
```

```css
#parent {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 20px; /* Increase/decrease this value for cross-browser compatibility */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div  id="child">In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
   'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
   'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
   'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically what it does is removing the padding right pixels and shows the scrollbar when the scroll is detected on the child element.

The bad thing about is you need to play with padding-right pixels for browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for that trick but i need to show scrollbar when user scroll page. right now content in div is overflow and a scrollbar s showing

Answer (score 1):

Consider using

`overflow : auto;`

> If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content

Comment: Currently overflow is clipped and scrollbar is showing but i want to hide scrollbar is overflow is clipped but show when user scroll pgae

Answer (score -1):

Try this simple solution with css only:

```
  .scrollbar {
      min-height: 500px;
      max-height: 500px;
      background: #f1f1f1;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
  .scrollbar:hover {
      overflow-y : auto;
    }
```

Comment: "When a page scrolls", not "When scrollbar is hovered on"

Answer (score -5):

It's an automatic feature,

you may try to set :

```
overflow : scroll;
```

to force it to work as you wanted.

You can also try `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`, depending on the axis you're scrolling.

Comment: Yes this is automatic feature but i need to show scrollbar only when user scroll. Can i hide scrollbar when page load and only show when user scroll page